# Problema al actualizar archivo .txt alojado en Gist Github - C#

Tags: c#, github, wpf, tokens

Estoy haciendo pruebas en `GitHub` con un archivo .txt y no consigo escribir / actualizarlo desde una aplicación de escritorio hecha en WPF con C#

A graso modo, tengo dos `métodos`, uno de lectura y el otro de escritura. Con el de lectura no tengo problema;

```
  private void BtActualizar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = "license.txt";
        string gistId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string rawUrl = $"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/User/{gistId}/raw/{fileName}";

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            tbServerLicense.Text = client.DownloadString(rawUrl);
        }
    }
```

Pero con el de escritura obtengo siempre el `error 403`, `System.Net.WebException: 'Error en el servidor remoto: (403) Prohibido.'`

He revisado el token muchas veces y en principio esta bien y tiene acceso a la parte de gist con lo cual debería poder escribir correctamente, sin embargo por muchas pruebas que haga siempre termino con el 403... El código es el siguiente;

```
private void BtGuardar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = "license.txt";
        string gistId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string rawUrl = $"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/User/{gistId}/raw/{fileName}";

        string content = "Hello, world!";

        string accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        string jsonPayload = $"{{ \"files\": {{ \"{fileName}\": {{ \"content\": \"{content}\" }} }} }}";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonPayload);

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, $"token {accessToken}");
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");

            try
            {
                byte[] response = client.UploadData(rawUrl, "PATCH", byteArray);
                Console.WriteLine("Archivo de texto actualizado con éxito.");
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Ocurrió un error al actualizar el archivo de texto: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

    }
```

En `Github`, ¿Hay que dar algún potro permiso además de crear el token y darle permisos de Gist?